# How to call a dynamic matrix into a function?

Tags: c++, matrix, memory, dynamic

I have declared a matrix this way:

```
double **MB;
    MB = new double *[650000];
     for (int count = 0; count < 650000; count++)
     MB[count] = new double [2];
```

Now I want to call my matrix in a function that should modify it.

```
bool notindic (..., double MB [][2], ...) {}
```

and in the main:

```
notindic(..., MB, ...)
```

Now it gives me this error: *[Error] cannot convert 'double**' to 'double (*)[2]' for argument '3' to 'bool notindic(std::string, std::string*, double (*)[2], int, int)'*

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: You are mixing dynamically allocated arrays with static arrays. There is no information available to the compiler to suggest that MB is an array. As far as it is concerned it is just a double**. So u shud change notindic to accept a double** parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass array pointer as parameter

```
#include <iostream>


const int NX = 65;
const int NY = 2;

bool notindic(double** MB) {
        for(int i = 0; i < NX; ++i) {
                for(int j = 0; j < NY; ++j) {
                        MB[i][j] = i + j;
                }
        }
}

int main() {
        double **MB = new double *[650000];
        for (int count = 0; count < 650000; count++) {
                MB[count] = new double [2];
        }

        notindic(MB);

        for(int i = 0; i < NX; ++i) {
                for(int j = 0; j < NY; ++j) {
                        std::cout << MB[i][j] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about all that pointer nonsense. It's error-prone, exception-unsafe, hard to write, hard to read, hard to maintain and may perform poorly. Represent your matrix as `std::vector<double>` and calculate the offsets accordingly.

```
bool notindic (std::vector<double> const& matrix, int m) {
    // ...
    auto const element = matrix[y * m + x];
    // ...
}

auto const m = 650000;
auto const n = 2;
std::vector<double> my_matrix(m * n);
auto const result = notindic(my_matrix, m);
```

While you're at it, wrap it in a class like this:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix final
{
public:
    Matrix(int m, int n) :
        data(m * n),
        m(m)
   {
   }

   T& operator()(int x, int y)
   {
       return data[y * m + x];
   }

   T const& operator()(int x, int y) const
   {
       return data[y * m + x];
   }

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
    int m;
};

bool notindic (Matrix<double> const& matrix) {
    // ...
    auto const element = matrix(x, y);
    // ...
}

auto const m = 650000;
auto const n = 2;
Matrix<double> my_matrix(m, n);
auto const result = notindic(my_matrix);
```

Add additional member functions if you need them.